# XML documentation does not show changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-documentation

I am starting with XML documentation for methods using this as guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288481(VS.71).aspx

But it appears that only the first time you enter documentation it will be picked up by IntelliSense.

This is the header of the method:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Add a Rit to the planning table.</summary>
/// <returns>
/// Returns the PlanningID for the inserted Planning.</returns>
public int AddRitToPlanning(int driverID, int truckID, int ritID, DateTime planningDate, int startTime, int hours)
```

Intellisense is only showing this:

> Add a Rit to the planning table.

and not the text in the `returns`.

I tried changing the text in the `summary` to something completely different but that too is not displayed by IntelliSense.

```
/// <summary> 
/// Complete other text here.</summary>
/// <returns>
/// Returns the PlanningID for the inserted Planning.</returns>
public int AddRitToPlanning(int driverID, int truckID, int ritID, DateTime planningDate, int startTime, int hours)
```

Then IntelliSense still displays:

> Add a Rit to the planning table.

**What I tried already**

- Checked the checkbox "Xml documentation file" in project properties/build.
- Rebuilt the project
- Restarted VS

**What I tried from the comments**
I cleaned the project and now the changes in the summary tag are shown by IntelliSense.

But the `returns` tag is still not shown so that problem remains.

How can I force IntelliSense to pick up my changes in the XML documentation and to show the text in the `returns` tag?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project/discarding the bin folders? This looks like a caching issue

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd what do you mean by cleaning the project/discarding the bin folders ? Do you mean right mouse on project and than choose rebuild ?

Comment: No, right-clicking the solution and selecting Clean. You can also delete de bin folder that is in the client project's folder

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd OK that solved my first problem, the change in the summary is now shown by intellisense. But the problem that the returns tag is not shown still remains. Any ideas about that maybe ?